# How to change true/false to [bootstrap] images

Tags: grails, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

By default in Grails, after the installation of the Twitter Bootstrap plugin (and its dependency: fields plugin), the view/packagename/show.gsp is like that:

[image: current show]

How could I use Bootstrap ([Glyphs Icons](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons)) to show something like this:

[image: wanted show]

Note: I actually will use [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/), but I wrote Bootstrap to simplify the question as it should be similar.

UPDATE: this is a piece of code of a boolean / logical property:

```
<g:if test="${safariInstance?.animalsAllowed}">
    <dt><g:message code="safari.animalsAllowed.label" default="Allow animals" /></dt>       
    <dd><g:formatBoolean boolean="${safariInstance?.animalsAllowed}" /></dd>        
</g:if>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach this in different ways, one example is:

```
...      
<td><i class="${safariInstance?.animalsAllowed?'icon-ok':'icon-remove'}" ></i> </td> 
...
```

Also you need to remove your '< g:if>' block to see both false and true options.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. A minor: I am using the [<dt> tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dt.asp) instead the [<td> tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_td.asp).

Comment: I am glad its working for you, the `< i >` tag and its class is important you can wrap it in any tag.